# role of constant of proportionality in complexity of algorithm

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

what is the role of the constant of proportionality while comparing the the order of complexities of two competing algorithms.

Like in case ALGO A has complexity **3*O(n)** while ALGO B has complexity **10*O(n)**,What will be the effect of constant of 3 and 10 here?

Answer (score 1):

The constants have no effect at all -- "$3\cdot O(n)$ and "$10\cdot O(n)$" both describe *the same class of functions*.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of f=O(g) is that there exists an n,m such that for every x>n, f(x) < M*g(x).
that's why the constant doesn't matter.
suppose ALGO A runs in 2*n binary operations, while ALGO B runs in n binary operations.
then both run in O(n) time complexity.

Comment: so what is the difference between ALGO A and B ???

Comment: This is hard to tell, since $3 \cdot O(n) = 10 \cdot O(n)$. The only thing we can say is that the algorithms take roughly linear time in the size of the input.

Comment: @JohannesKloos: Strictly speaking, roughly linear time would be $\Theta(n)$, not $O(n)$.

Comment: @Aryabhata: True, but that was roughly what I meant by "roughly" :) I tend to assume that an algorithm will consume all its input, so it will have $\Omega(n)$ time-complexity.

Comment: @JohannesKloos: So, do you hate binary-search? :-) Just kidding...

Comment: @shariq There is no difference. we can even say that, for example, the algorithm for finding the minimum of an array of n numbers is O(n), and it's also 3*O(n), and 1.2345234234234*O(n). there is no difference. although n*O(n) is not the same as O(n), because n is not a constant.

Answer (score 0):

you can judge the importance of constant of proportionality  by comparing insertion sort (c1.n^2),and merge sort(c2.nlogn).
  insertion sort is better when n is small,because of only single reason ie c1